# Reading android account data

Tags: android

I have installed an android app on my phone which has created an account which I can see under settings>accounts. I want to be able to find out what information is stored there. Is this possible?

I presume it stores data on the app owners servers, so I would like to know what this data is. Or is the data stored in my google account somewhere?

Where can I find some android developer documentation for this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad news, unfortunately. This process is usually done using [sync adapters](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/), or at least [the Account Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager) component. (e.g. [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth)). Whilst some information can be obtained, most is hidden.

Put simply, there is no folder / file where the information for an account is stored, and therefore you cannot access it.

The login data is stored by the OS, and can therefore be queried for basic info like username / email ([source](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify#TaskFive)):

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

`MyActivity.java`:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this); // "this" references the current Context
Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
String name = accounts.toString()
```

The actual information sent and received however is handled entirely by the app itself, meaning there's no way for you to view the information it has about you. This could be on a server somewhere, or encrypted, or not even exist. You could potentially try intercepting all traffic to & from your device, but this is outside the scope of this question.

The easiest way to find out what information an app has about you is to ask the company. In the UK for example, you can file a [Subject Access Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_Act_1998#Subject_Access_Requests).